# Why am I getting this simple error when using `acts_as_taggable_on`?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, passenger, acts-as-taggable-on

I wanted to set up `ActsAsTaggableOn.strict_case_match = true`
According to http://5minutenpause.com/blog/2012/11/20/careful-where-you-get-your-gems-from/, it seems I have to download the gem from github. So I made it that way and tried to run App.

However, it returns this error:(

**Error message:** (I've tried `bundle install` but still the same error message!)

```
git://github.com/mbleigh/acts-as-taggable-on.git (at master) is not checked out. Please run `bundle install` (Bundler::GitError)
Exception class:
    PhusionPassenger::UnknownError
```

---

Here are my codes!

- config/initializer/tag_list.rb

  `ActsAsTaggableOn.delimiter = ','`
  `ActsAsTaggableOn.remove_unused_tags = true`
  `ActsAsTaggableOn.strict_case_match = true`
- Gemfile

  `gem 'acts-as-taggable-on', git: 'git://github.com/mbleigh/acts-as-taggable-on.git'`

---

I made a try to change the source to download the gem directly from to rubyorg, not from the Github. It's just like this.

```
gem 'acts-as-taggable-on', '2.3.3'
```

Now it returns this error:(

**Error message:**

```
undefined method `strict_case_match=' for ActsAsTaggableOn:Module
```

How can I solve this?

UPDATE:

**Gemfile**

```
source 'https://rubygems.org'

gem 'rails', '3.2.11'

# Bundle edge Rails instead:
# gem 'rails', :git => 'git://github.com/rails/rails.git'

gem 'mysql2'
gem 'execjs'
gem 'therubyracer'
gem 'devise', '2.0.1'
gem 'recaptcha', :require => 'recaptcha/rails'
gem 'paperclip', "~> 3.0"
gem "cocaine" 
gem 'mailboxer', '0.7.0'
gem 'sunspot_rails'
gem 'sunspot_solr'
group :development do
    gem 'better_errors'
    gem 'binding_of_caller'
    #gem 'rack-mini-profiler'
end
gem 'progress_bar'
gem 'kaminari', '0.14.0'
gem "sunspot_with_kaminari", '~> 0.1'
gem 'i18n_generators'
gem 'ancestry'
gem 'acts-as-taggable-on', '2.3.3'

gem 'acts_as_commentable_with_threading'

gem 'twitter-bootstrap-rails'
gem "less-rails"

gem 'crummy', '~> 1.6.0'

gem 'rails3_acts_as_paranoid'

gem 'galetahub-simple_captcha', :require => 'simple_captcha'

gem "acts_as_follower"

gem "jpmobile"

gem "rqrcode-rails3"

gem 'acts_as_votable', '~> 0.4.0'

gem 'rails3-jquery-autocomplete'

gem "cancan"

gem 'rinku', '1.5.1'

gem 'dalli'

gem "auto_html", '1.6.0'

gem "rails_autolink"




# Gems used only for assets and not required
# in production environments by default.
group :assets do
  gem 'sass-rails',   '~> 3.2.3'
  gem 'coffee-rails', '~> 3.2.1'

  # See https://github.com/sstephenson/execjs#readme for more supported runtimes
  # gem 'therubyracer', :platforms => :ruby

  gem 'uglifier', '>= 1.0.3'
  gem 'jquery-ui-rails'

end

gem 'jquery-rails'



# To use ActiveModel has_secure_password
# gem 'bcrypt-ruby', '~> 3.0.0'

# To use Jbuilder templates for JSON
# gem 'jbuilder'

# Use unicorn as the app server
# gem 'unicorn'

# Deploy with Capistrano
# gem 'capistrano'

# To use debugger
# gem 'debugger'
```

Answer (score 2):

The problem is that the version 2.3.3 from acts-as-taggable-on was released 9 months ago and doesn't include the **strict_case_match** feature.

Your Gemfile has too look this this:

```
gem 'acts-as-taggable-on', git: 'git://github.com/mbleigh/acts-as-taggable-on.git'
```

the same way you had, and run:

```
bundle update acts-as-taggable-on
```

if that doesn't work, just delete your Gemfile.lock and run bundle install and bundle update

notice that its a development version of the gem, not ready for production, but you can take the risk and be a an alpha user of the gem and report any issue you find :)

Comment: Thanks for reply:) I tried everything what you told me to do.  But it's still getting the same error.

Comment: ups, sorry about that, you have your code with git, right? just run: **git reset Gemfile.lock**

Comment: It's okay. just one gem was losing a feature. So I added exact version to Gemfile for that. It's all fine now.  what does `git reset Gemfile.lock` do? Do you think it would solve my problem?

Comment: git reset Gemfile.lock, if you are using git for your source code, just revert the updates to the last commit.

Comment: Can you just put the content of your Gemfile, I may ble able to help if I see it

Comment: Thanks. I've updated and added it to my question.  By the way current version of `acts_as_taggable_on` officially supports `ActsAsTaggableOn.strict_case_match = true`? If so, which version??

Comment: I just tried your Gemfile, ran **bundle**, then updated the acts-as-taggable to be checked out from the source code as I wrote, and ran: **bundle install** and worked fine. How are you running your app? update the Gemfile to get acts-as-taggable from the git source code, then do **bundle install** and finally try to run the app with: **bundle exec script/rails server** and let me know

Comment: The current version (2.3.3) of acts_as_taggable_on was released 9 months ago, and it didn't support **strict_case_match** at that point, the new version which is under development, supports **strict_case_match** but has not been released yet, when you tell Gemfile to get the gem from the git repository, its going to get the latest code from the repository, which is still under development, we can say its an "alpha" version.

Comment: Thanks for the perfect explanation. Now, I understood all the situation about this gem. Was it able for you to find how to solve this by taking a look at my whole Gemfile?

Comment: I wanted to be sure that the "bundle install" or the "bundle update acts_as_taggable_on" were actually installing the latest code from the git repo, and it was. Then I read your question again and I realized that you were probably running the app with a different environment to the one that you use for the bundler installation. BTW, did the **bundle exec** worked for the app, or it still ask you to run **bundle install** ?

Comment: Just bundle install will be fine for my environment